# Android architecture: MutableStateFlow in Repository is ok?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Let's simplify our app to 3 layers: Jetpack Compose UI, VM and Repository.
Simple question: what is the best approach for event type between both layers and why.

For example, I have **VM** with **MutableState** (exposed to UI as a **State**). Is it a problem or should I have **MutableStateFlow** for VM state?

Another layer is a **Repository** (or UseCase, or Interactor in more complex scenario). I've tried **MutableState**, and it works more or less fine. I've tried **MutableStateFlow** with collecting in VM  - and this works perfect from my perspective.

So, what is the best common pattern right now?

I've tried **MutableStateFlow** in Repository and **MutableState** in ViewModel.

Comment: this is quite a general question, I suggest you take this to a platform like Reddit or LinkedIn

Comment: To answer your question, in my _opinion_ , it is not a good approach to have anything reactive unless it is generated by a library or SDK in the layer below VM or Presenter, Since we dispose off the VM or Presenter as soon as we leave the place.

Comment: This question is off-topic since it is opinion-based. But generally, for modularity reasons, it's preferable not to use UI-/platform-specific types like State in other layers of your app. The further from the UI, the worse, and the repository is about as far as you can get from the UI. The ViewModel is closer to UI. Some would say not to use State in the ViewModel because it should be a platform-agnostic layer. But it is definitely more convenient and concise if you do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "Are hammers better than pliers?" question. One is not inherently better than the other, it depends on what you want it to do.

`MutableState` - you have to handle updates from data manually (you don't receive events on value change) - `MutableState` is more or less nothing but a simple variable.

`MutableStateFlow` - consumers receive updates when the data changes.

Neither of those are good or bad, they are just different tools for different problems.

"*Is it a problem*? No.

"`MutableStateFlow` *in* **Repository** *is ok*?" With all that was said above, yes.

**Repository** should expose `Flow` and the consumer shouldn't know or care anything beyond that.

Also, you don't need to collect it in **VM**, you can just create `map` function that will transform the original input stream.

Comment: Regarding map function. For multiple sources in VM is a common approach just to zip and map all Flows to a single State?

Comment: @AndrewUnknown [Yes](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/738e1e008096fad5f36612325275e80c33dbe436/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/feed/FeedViewModel.kt#L211C46-L211C46)

Comment: Often the repository would want to expose `StateFlow` instead if you need to access the value directly without the Flow. The real question is if you can/should expose `MutableStateFlow` instead of `StateFlow` with backing variable underneath it.